# How to retrieve setAttribute from servlet into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I'm trying to retrieve the value of my setAttribute into my javascript code but I get a syntax error when I run the page.

Here is the code of my setAttribute in my servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("codeIGA", codeIGA); //a string is being passed here
```

Here is the code of my JS:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        var count = 0;
        var lastCodeIGA =  ${sessionScope.codeIGA}; // syntax error here
        console.log(lastCodeIGA);
            .
            .
            . 
            etc
```

How can I retrieve the value from my servlet and input it into my JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to retrieve the required value.

```
var lastCodeIGA =  '${codeIGA}';
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Try with scriptlet.

```
var test = <%=request.getAttribute("codeIGA");
```

Or

```
var lastCodeIGA = '${codeIGA}';
```